# Multiple outlets with Multi-Scenes and ViewControllers for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, outlet

So I have have three scenes with three individual textFields. I set up three ViewControllers for each of the scenes to handle dismissing the keyboard on each respective textField in it's own scene. But I can't get the textField object to create a IBAction outlet using the control drag method. Even created a custom UITextField class to try and resolve the solution but that didn't seem to help. Any ideas why I can't get this to work?

**Here is my Storyboard set up:**

[image: Storyboard]

**This is what it looks like when I try an control drag**
[image: Control Drag Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution. Even though the `UITextField` had it's own class the scene it's self I had was under the wrong `UIViewController` class. I selected the `UIViewController` by selecting the black bar underneath it (this can also be done using **Document Outline** or **Shft+Cntrl+Click** and selecting the proper `UIViewController`) and changing the `Custom Class` setting under the Identity Inspector to that of the `UIViewController` that I intend to interact with it.